# Unable to run flask api in browser

Tags: python, flask

Very simple flask app ..

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/api')
def main():
    print( "Welcome!")
    print(10+2)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Executed this code in and shows me 
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

But unable to access this api in browser.

Comment: The indentation on that looks odd - for it to work properly, the `@app.route` line should be at the same level of indentation as the `def main():` line. Is that how your file is currently indented?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to access"? Can you describe what happens more precisely?

Comment: Firstly your route is `api`, so I'd expect to access it using http://127.0.0.1:5000/api, there is no route registered for `/`. Secondly your `main` function returns nothing. `print` outputs to the console, you need to return whatever you expect to see in the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `return` instead of `print` that's because the latter prints to the terminal where you started the flask app and doesn't actually send anything to the client who's using the API.

Here's a working example:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api')
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then go to `localhost:5000/api` to see the `Wecome!` message.

To get started with flask, I highly recommend the [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) tutorial in the official documentation.

Comment: Yes..you save my life. Many thanks to you...can you please recommend me few articles for same subject.

Comment: @user3193177 glad I could help. I highly suggest that you start here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

Comment: @user3193177 this one is good too: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world